# To find degree of following differential equation $(y^")^{1/2}=(y^")^5$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose given DE is

$(y^")^{1/2}=(y^")^5$.

I have to find degree of this DE.

Note : To study degree of a differential equation, it must be a polynomial in derivatives, i.e. $y', y'', y'''$, etc. i.e. derivative terms must be free from fractions, radicals and transcendent functions.

Squaring both sides, we get,

$y^"=(y^")^{10}$.

I am confused about next step.

From here I can conclude degree is 10 but what if $y^"$ is nonzero for all $x$. Can it be $9$ then by dividing throughout by $y''$?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess $10$ would be correct, since you lose the solutions with $y''=0$ if you divide. But the first step in solving it would probably be factoring it into a $1$ and a $9$ degree DE.

Comment: Order, easy: $2$.  Degree (as in the title)?  You will need to provide a definition for "degree of a differential equation".  For degree of a **polynomial**, we say $X^{10}-X$ has degree $10$, even though $X$ may be nonzero and can be factored out.

Comment: @GEdgar I have added the definition

Answer (score 4):

The **order** of a differential equation is the *order of the highest derivative that appears in the equation*. Since
$$(y\color{red}{''})^{1/2}=(y\color{red}{''})^{5},\quad y=y(x)$$
so you have a *second order* nonlinear differential equation.

Comment: My question is about degree sir..

Comment: Well, your question in the *post* says "I have to find *order* of this DE." For the other question, you must be add the definition of "degree of DE" that's important here. Add that information in your post. I suppose that "degree of DE" refers to the highest power of $y^{(n)}$ but you need to add the definition in your post.

Comment: Sorry for typo.. I will add definition of degree in the post

Comment: I have added the definition